# ExpressJS video streaming has annoying audio issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, audio, video

I have been attempting to run an ExpressJS web server that serves videos from my filesystem. For some reason, whenever a video is played, there is constant popping sounds and eventually (after 3-10 minutes) the audio cuts out entirely. Reloading the page will bring the audio back, but won't stop the popping.

I have 2 different methods for serving the video, but only 1 is used at runtime. They both serve to this function:

```
app.get(`/${VIDTYPE}/:path`, (req, res) => {
    let p = decode(req.params.path)
    let dir = path.dirname(p)
    let name = path.parse(p).name
    let ext = '.vtt'

    let track = path.resolve(`${dir}/${name}${ext}`)

    console.log({track})

    res.send(
        `<video id="videoplayer" controls width="90%" height="90%">` +
        `<source src="/video/${req.params.path}"/>` +
        `<track default kind="subtitles" label="en" src="/track/${encode(track)}"/>` +
        `</video>`
    )
})
```

The first method was copied from the internet and felt rather complicated.

```
app.get("/video/:path", (req, res) => {
    let decoded = decode(req.params.path)
    console.log("video", {decoded})
    let stat = fs.statSync(decoded)
    let fileSize = stat.size
    let range = req.headers.range

    if (range) {
        const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
        const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
        const end = parts[1] 
            ? parseInt(parts[1], 10)
            : fileSize-1
        const chunksize = (end-start)+1
        const file = fs.createReadStream(decoded, {start, end})
        const head = {
            'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Content-Length': chunksize,
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        }
        res.writeHead(206, head);
        file.pipe(res);
    } else {
        const head = {
            'Content-Length': fileSize,
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
            }
        res.writeHead(200, head)
        fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
    }
})
```

The second method is much simpler and seems to function the same way. Both of them have the audio issues with no discernible difference in quality.

```
app.get("/video2/:path", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(decode(req.params.path))
})
```

The full codebase will be in the comments. All mp4 files were converted from mkv using ffmpeg, so that could be causing issues, but none of the videos have the same audio problems when played directly. I have also isolated the issue to mobile.

Any ideas on where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

codebase:

```
const { json } = require('body-parser')
const { dir } = require('console')
const { response } = require('express')
const express = require('express')
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

const port = 80

const app = express()

const vid_ext = [
    '.mp4',
    '.webm'
]

const VIDTYPE = "vid"
const DIRTYPE = "dir"

const getAllFiles = function(dirPath) {
    console.log({dirPath});
    files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath)

    arrayOfFiles = [{
        path: path.join(dirPath + "/.."),
        title: "go up(beta)",
        type: DIRTYPE
    }]

    files.forEach(function(file) {
        let p = path.resolve(path.join(dirPath, "/", file))
        if (fs.statSync(dirPath + "/" + file).isDirectory()) {
            arrayOfFiles.push({ 
                path: p,
                title: file,
                type: DIRTYPE
            })
        } else {
            if (vid_ext.includes(path.extname(p))) {
                arrayOfFiles.push({
                    path: p,
                    title: file,
                    type: VIDTYPE
                })
            }
        }
    })

    return arrayOfFiles
}

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.redirect(`/${DIRTYPE}/${encode("../stuff")}`);
});

app.get(`/${DIRTYPE}/:path`, (req, res) => {
    let decoded = decode(req.params.path)
    console.log(DIRTYPE, decoded)

    res.send(dirtable(decoded))
})

app.get("/video/:path", (req, res) => {
    let decoded = decode(req.params.path)
    console.log("video", {decoded})
    let stat = fs.statSync(decoded)
    let fileSize = stat.size
    let range = req.headers.range

    if (range) {
        const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
        const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
        const end = parts[1] 
            ? parseInt(parts[1], 10)
            : fileSize-1
        const chunksize = (end-start)+1
        const file = fs.createReadStream(decoded, {start, end})
        const head = {
            'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Content-Length': chunksize,
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        }
        res.writeHead(206, head);
        file.pipe(res);
    } else {
        const head = {
            'Content-Length': fileSize,
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
            }
        res.writeHead(200, head)
        fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
    }
})

app.get("/video2/:path", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(decode(req.params.path))
})

app.get(`/${VIDTYPE}/:path`, (req, res) => {
    let p = decode(req.params.path)
    let dir = path.dirname(p)
    let name = path.parse(p).name
    let ext = '.vtt'

    let track = path.resolve(`${dir}/${name}${ext}`)

    console.log({track})

    res.send(
        `<video id="videoplayer" controls width="90%" height="90%">` +
        `<source src="/video/${req.params.path}"/>` +
        `<track default kind="subtitles" label="en" src="/track/${encode(track)}"/>` +
        `</video>`
    )
    //res.redirect(`/video2/${req.params.path}`)
})

app.get("/track/:path", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(decode(req.params.path))
})

function dirtable(a) {
    let files = getAllFiles(a)

    return (
        "<table><tbody>" + 
        files.map(x => `<td>${linkfrom(x)}</td><td>${x.type}</td>`).reduce((acc, x) => acc + `<tr>${x}</tr>`) +
        "</tbody></table>"
    )
}

function linkfrom(a) {
    return `<a href="/${a.type}/${encode(a.path)}">${a.title}</a>`
}

function encode(h) {
    return Buffer.from(h).toString('base64')
}

function decode(h) {
    return Buffer.from(h, "base64").toString()
}

app.listen(port, console.log(`App Listening to port ${port}`));
```